Does the smooth locus of any toric variety built from a fan always contain a rational point?
Let $k$ be an arbitrary field and $X$ be a toric variety built from a fan, defined over $k$.
Does the smooth locus of $X$ always contain a $k$-rational point? Why?

Sure, the interior of the toric variety is a split torus, so its rational points are in bijection with $(k^{\times})^n$. Is there some definition of toric variety where this isn't true?

Thank you very much for your kind help.

Why does the torus need to be split? One can obtain non-split tori if the fan has a non-trivial Galois action. In any case the result is also true for non-split tori.

So, I wasn't being purely rhetorical. I can believe that there might be a definition where you can have a T-torsor, rather than a torus, as the big cell. I just don't know such a definition. If you are following Fulton's Toric Varieties book, the torus is split.

In the modern theory, it is more useful to allow toric varieties over general fields constructed through fans with a Galois action, in which case one obtains non-split tori. I believe this was first considered in: Batyrev, Victor V.; Tschinkel, Yuri. Rational points of bounded height on compactifications of anisotropic tori. Internat. Math. Res. Notices 1995, no. 12, 591--635

Anyway, the answer to the question is "depends on your definition of toric variety". Some authors allow a torsor as the dense open set which need not have a rational point. See this paper for example:
Elizondo, E. Javier; Lima-Filho, Paulo; Sottile, Frank; Teitler, Zach. Arithmetic toric varieties. Math. Nachr. 287 (2014), no. 2-3, 216--241

Okay, if a toric variety is a normal variety with a torus action that has a dense orbit, then take $k = \mathbb{R}$, take $T = \text{SO}(2) = \left{ \begin{bmatrix} u&-v \ v&u \end{bmatrix} : u^2+v^2=1 \right}$ and take $X = { (x:y:z) \ : \ x^2+y^2+z^2=0 } \subset \mathbb{P}^2$, with the action by $ \begin{bmatrix} u&-v&0 \ v&u&0 \ 0&0&1 \end{bmatrix}$. Then $X$ is smooth, but has no $\mathbb{R}$ points.
